# Python - How do I use user input as an array name?

Tags: python, arrays, list

I'm making a game where someone can select a square via notation and then perform an action on that square. Think chess, i.e. perform action on a2 or a3.

I need a2, for example, to be an array. How can I take a user's input and make it the name of the array?

I can basically make it work with:

```
if user_input == "a2":
  a2 = ["value 1"]
elif user_input == "a3":
  a3 = ["value 1"]
```

etc.

I'm thinking there has to be a better way. That's a lot of overhead and not easily scalable.

-mS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a `dict`, you'll be able to set keys at runtime:

```
board = dict()
square = user_input
board[square] = ["value 1"]
```

This will free you of the need to handle all squares one by one in the code, which is I think your question was about.

Comment: That's what I needed. I had thought about dictionaries, but didn't realize you could put multiple values in. Tested and working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary:

```
h = {}
if user_input == "a2":
  h["a2"] = ["value 1"]
elif user_input == "a3":
  h["a3"] = ["value 1"]
```

Now, the good thing is that you can factorize your code:

```
h = {}
h[user_input] = ["value 1"]
```

Comment: Wait, _hashes_ are different from hash-tables or Python dictionaries, right?

Comment: "You can't name variables at runtime" --  you can by adding new entries into the `globals()` dictionary, although doing so is seldom motivated.

Comment: Edit due to comments 1 and 3, I'm obviously not good enough in python to make statements like this.
@ForceBru About *hash*, I changed it because in Python the name is *dictionary* (I was thinking the ruby way). However, the implementation behind is the same: PHP's *array*, Python's *dictionary*, Ruby's *hash*, all of those are associative arrays which are implemented using a hash map (or hash table, but the difference is [tiny](http://www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-hashtable-and-hashmap/)).